# Create a binary tree from a sorted array list

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I need to program a Huffman compression for Text for an university assignment.
The exercise is split in to multiple points, and one of them is to create a binary tree from a given sorted arrayList which is of type TreeNode, this class looks like this (I removed the method boddies):

```
public class TreeNode implements Comparable<TreeNode>, Serializable {

    private byte value;

    private int frequency;

    private TreeNode left, right;

    /** Creates new TreeNode .. must get initialized with value */
    public TreeNode(byte value) {
        this(value, 0, null, null);
    }

    /** Creates new TreeNode with full init */
    public TreeNode(byte value, int frequency, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        this.value = value;
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    public void incFrequency()
    public int getFreq()
    public Byte getValue()
    public TreeNode getLeft()
    public TreeNode getRight() 
    public boolean isLeaf()
    public int getSubTreeSize() 
    public void toHeap(byte[] heap, int myIndex) 
    public void initLookup(long myCode, int myDepth, Map<Byte, BitCode> lookupTable)
    @Override
    public int compareTo(TreeNode o)
    @Override
    public String toString()
    public void printSubTree(PrintStream out, int tabs)
    public void write(BitStream bs)
    public static TreeNode read(BitStream bs)

}
```

I need to create a binary tree from an arrayList of type TreeNode, the arrayList is sorted by value so I can assume that the element with the smalles value is at index position 0.
The tree has to fulfill one important condition: 
The element with the next bigger value needs to be appended on the left, and the element with an even bigger value needs to be appended to the right (the tree will be builded always to the right).

My attemp to approach this problem was to iterate over the list, getting the item, and then appending each item with an odd index to the left leave of the previous node and each item with an even index to the right leave.

Is there a more elegant way to approach this?
(I dont ask you to do the homework for me, but I could need some ideas)

EDIT:
I need to keep the SortedList, since it is a part of the exercise specification

Comment: Does your approach work? Based on your description, it doesn't sound like it would (although it's fairly close to something that would), but the phrasing in your question makes it sound like it does work.

Comment: @Dukeling It does not work

Comment: Try drawing the tree on paper to see what you should connect. Your approach just needs a minor change to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally, after some headache, found a solution to this problem.

1. I iterated over the List of TreeNode,
2. I removed the first item from the list and stored it in a tempoary variable called "left", I did the same thing again and called that "right" since the list is sorted this will always deliver the biggest and 2nd biggest (in terms of frequency) element of the list.
3. I added a new TreeNode to the tree, which has as value 0, as frequency the sum of the frequency of the left and left and right TreeNode and a left and right the left and right which were removed from the list in step 2.
4. I sorted the list again.
5. These steps where repeated as long as the tree has a size of more than 1 element.

My code looks like this:

```
private void initializeTree(List tree) {
```

```
do{

    TreeNode left = tree.remove(0);
    TreeNode right = tree.remove(0);

    tree.add(new TreeNode((byte)0, left.getFreq() + right.getFreq(), left, right));

    Collections.sort(tree);

}while(tree.size() > 1);

root = tree.get(0);
printTree(System.out);
```

}

The method print tree is a static method if this class which justs prints the tree to the console, the root variable is the root node of the binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

Only for the sake of helping you, you could think along the following lines:

1. select the middle element as the root node
2. split the array list into two - left starting from 0 to mid-1, and right starting from mid+1 to last
3. Recursively repeat step 1 till there is only one element left in the array.
4. Return that element when only one is left.

Editing my answer as i didn't understand the requirements properly initially.

First Edit - 
You could do something like this - 
0. If no element, return
1. make first element your root.
2. make next element if it exists as the left child.
3. recursively call the function making its result the right child.

Comment: That would generate a evenly distrubuted tree, but I need a tree that fulfils the condition of having the smaller element at the left and the larger one at the right since the tree is lateron the codetable for the Hufmancompression and the codewords come from this tree

Comment: An evenly distributed binary search tree has smaller elements to the left and larger ones to the right. For example if your array was like this - 10, 15, 20, 25, 30.
the tree made by the above logic will be ---  (10 -> 15) <- 20 -> 25-> 30

Comment: OP doesn't want a binary search tree. As I under the description in the question, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 should give a tree with 10 as the root, with children 15 and 20, and 20 should have children 25 and 30.